# Lorentz fitting issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to fit a Lorentz peak to some data and the fit seems to function however it does not show up on the graph.

```
#Defining a Lorentz function to fit a curve to the data which is used in the plot() to create a graph 
def lorentz(M,M0,delM):
    d=read()
    M=d[:,0]
    n=delM
    d=(M-M0)**2+(delM/2)**2
    s=(1/2*pi)*(n/d)
    #Multiplying s by 7.943E5 to convert tesla to A/m for a more sensible umerical answer
    return s*(7.943E5)

#Creating a graph plot of Absorption against Magnetic field for magnetic resonance and using lorentz() to fit a curve to the data    
def plot():
    d=read()
    M=d[:,0]
    A=d[:,1]

    pyplot.semilogx(M,A,marker=".",ls="none", label="20 Ghz")
    fit_vals, fit_errors = curve_fit(lorentz,M,A)
    pyplot.semilogx(M, lorentz(M, fit_vals[0], fit_vals[1]), label = "fit")
    pyplot.xlabel("Magnetic Field,A/m")
    pyplot.ylabel("Absorption")
    pyplot.title("Magnetic resonance")
    pyplot.legend()

    pyplot.show()
```

Comment: I assume read() is an implemented function that returns a numpy array? Also what are the dimensions of this array?

Comment: We would greatly appreciate if you actually read the help->tour and leave out chit-chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code runs for me:

```
import numpy as np
from  matplotlib import pyplot 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def fn(x, a, b, c):
   return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

d=np.random.rand(50,2)
M=d[:,0]
A=d[:,1]

fit_vals, fit_errors = curve_fit(fn,M,A)


print ' fit coefficients:\n', fit_vals
print ' Covariance matrix:\n', fit_errors

polynomial = np.poly1d(fit_vals)

xs = np.arange(0,1,0.01)
ys = polynomial(xs)

pyplot.semilogx(M, A,'o', label = "fit")
pyplot.semilogx(xs, ys, label = "fit")

pyplot.xlabel("Magnetic Field,A/m")
pyplot.ylabel("Absorption")
pyplot.title("Magnetic resonance")
pyplot.legend()

pyplot.show()
```

I use two columns of a random array to make the plot.

[image: Output]

Comment: The issue for me is I am using data which fits a certain lorentz function as can be seen in the code but when the graph is plotted it simply plots the points and not the fit I have estimated.

Comment: Okay that is now clearer to me. I shall look into it in a bit @Jackal

Comment: @Jackal - i have not used the lorentz function in the example, but it should do what you want